# Autoscaler Launching a simple python script on an AWS ray cluster with docker EXAMPLES

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, distributed-computing, ray

I am finding with ray a serious lack of documentation for the autoscaling. I cannot get anything to work.

Does anyone know of any basic examples of autoscaling with aws that I can build into. ie. dockerfile (or without docker, not fussy at this point), config.yaml simple_ray_script.py

or anything at all that I can just download and run.

The examples I have tried with minimal.yaml are too simple, such that any changes to the config, ie applying a conda env stops workers from being initiate and a multitude of other issues. The examples don't work for me either in ray project

That would be great.

so far I have found pretty much nothing that works. I just want to run a simple ray python script WITH dependencies that will also launch and run on all workers, NOT just on head cluster.

Comment: Could you post an issue on the Ray Discussion Forums? We'd be happy to take a close look/help you get things working!

Comment: Here's the link to the discussion forums -- https://discuss.ray.io/ :)